# Parse first name from full name in Sql Server

Tags: sql

I need to parse first name from last name,space first name space middle name.
For example:

I need to parse 'CHRISTINA' from the full name 'LONG, CHRISTINA F'. There is a space between ',' and 'CHRISTINA' and another space between 'CHRISTINA' AND 'F'

I can parse 'CHRISTINA' if there is no space between ',' and 'CHRISTINA' 
using :

select LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING( 'LONG,CHRISTINA F ', CHARINDEX(',', 'LONG,CHRISTINA F ') + 1, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ', 'LONG,CHRISTINA F ', CHARINDEX(',', 'LONG,CHRISTINA F ')), 0), 8000) - (CHARINDEX(',', 'LONG,CHRISTINA F ') + 1))))

Thanks,

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  Also more examples in the form of sample data and desired results is recommended.

Comment: Show us what you have attempted..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming SQL Server you should be able to do something like this:

```
DECLARE @fullName varchar(50)
DECLARE @startIndex int
DECLARE @secondIndex int
DECLARE @firstName varchar(20)

SET @fullName = 'LONG, CHRISTINA F'
SET @startIndex = CHARINDEX(',', @fullName)
SET @secondIndex = CHARINDEX(' ', @fullName, @startIndex + 2)
SET @firstName = Substring(@fullName, @startIndex + 1, @secondIndex - @startIndex)

SELECT @firstName
```

Comment: @Ice - if that's the case please mark this as the answer (the tick next to the upvote / downvote arrows).